# Declaring Arrays of known custom class types in obj C/ios

Tags: ios, arrays

Is there anyway to declare an array of custom class type in ios. eg if I have a custom class called GenericProduct, is there a way to declare an array of objects of this type only in ios instead of NSArray or NSMutableArray.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, though potentially you could subclass and ensure only valid types were inserted into the class.

At heart though Objective-C is a dynamically typed system, so it's a bit unnatural to force container types in that way and you may break unexpectedly as a result (like what happens when a JSON parser gives you back a mixture of NSNumber, NSString and NSNull objects?

Answer (score 1):

Since all objective-c objects are at heart c-structs, you can just declare a plain c array of your objective-c objects, like

```
GenericProduct *array[5];
```

Or if you mean to enforce type checking when inserting an object into the array, potentially you can subclass the NSMutableArray class to do the checking, though this is not really necessary per se.

Comment: however if I do this, I guess I will have to allocate memory using malloc and would not be able to use the convenience initializers of nsarray etc right?

Comment: Yes you will have to, if you do not want to subclass NSArray / NSMutableArray to perform type checking. Seriously though, you should use the generic NSArray and do your type checking elsewhere.

Comment: thank you for confirming this :-).. I guess I'll choose the design to be dynamic instead of subclassing..

Answer (score 1):

Now with Generics you specific what type the NSArray is containing.

For example:

```
NSMutableArray<GenericProduct *> *array = [NSMutableArray array];
```

The same thing can be done in Swift

```
var array = [GenericProduct]()
```

or more explicitly

```
var array = Array<GenericProduct>()
```

Now Swift will strictly enforce this type checking. While in ObjC, it is simply a guideline for us human developers and will not throw an error at compile time.

Obviously, there is still the C array option that **@futureelite7** mentioned.

A real world example using [Apple's ObjC Runtime Library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418579-objc_getclasslist?language=objc)

```
int numberOfClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0); 
Class *classes = (__unsafe_unretained Class *)malloc(sizeof(Class) * numberOfClasses);
numberOfClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numberOfClasses);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClasses; i++) {
   Class class = classes[i];
   //do something with it
}
```